# Assign more than one function to OnBeign

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, ajax.beginform

Is there a way to assign more than one javascript function to `OnBegin` in `Ajax.BeginForm()`, while passing some parameters (ie `xhr` and `status`) to one of them, e.g.

```csarp
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "convertContractorToAnEmployeeFormAjaxContainer",
    OnBegin = "(function(xhr, status){ oneFunction(xhr, status); anotherOne();})();"
}))
{
    //...
}
```

When you provide one function name for `OnBegin` you've got three arguments `xhr`, `status`, `error`. How do I handle it inline?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `OnBegin` only has one argument, `xhr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do by wrapping your calls in an anonymous function.

For example:

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml:**

```cs
<div id='ajaxStatus'></div>
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm("Test", "Home", new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnBegin = "new function(){func1(xhr); func2();}",
        UpdateTargetId = "ajaxStatus",
    })
)
{
    <input type='submit' />
}

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function func1(xhr) {
            console.log("xhr: ", xhr);
        }

        function func2(){
            console.log("func2 called");
        }

    </script>
}
```

**HomeController.cs:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public MvcHtmlString Test(object form)
{
    return new MvcHtmlString("success");
}
```

---

Also, a small note: `OnBegin`'s available argument is `xhr`.

Here is a list of the arguments available for each of the [AjaxOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) event properties:

- [OnBegin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onbegin%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) – xhr
- [OnComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.oncomplete%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) – xhr, status
- [OnSuccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onsuccess%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) – data, status, xhr
- [OnFailure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onfailure%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) – xhr, status, error

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I was confused because when you provide only name of function then `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` assigns `arguments` object to that function. In my case the `arguments` contains two elements which both I use now. But when you provide anonymous function like above then I can get only xhr:-/ I think that I have to get around this by write another function and in that one call  the both:-/